# localstorage and rest webservice in sencha touch

Tags: rest, proxy, sencha-touch, local-storage

i have an application that is currently processing data through a webservice. How can I be able to set it up in such a way that it can also work offline? (since the proxy that is currently set up is json and I understand that to work offline one must set the proxy to localstorage).

Answer (score 0):

Read the localstorage details in Sencha API. You need to add a localstorage proxy to your model and the store will automatically add the data in localstorage. But remember to make a check each time before adding to localstore whether the same data is already there or not.

You will get better explanation at sencha docs [localstorage](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage) details.